# How to make pair through bluetooth to zebra mz320 printter?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am implementing one app.

Based on my requirement, I want to take a printout from a **zebra mz320 printer** through mobile bluetooth.

I am trying to make a pair from `mobile bluetooth` to `printer bluetoth.`

When I try to pair, the printer throws a message like "Type 1234 or 0000 PIN for make
connection.

I typed the same PIN.

But the printer is not paired to my mobile device.

It throws an exception like `com.zebra.android.comm.ZebraPrinterConnectionException: Could not connect to printer: Unable to start Service Discovery`

If anyone knows the solution, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to get the UUID of the printer. listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord (String name, UUID uuid)

Answer (score 1):

UUIDs list see [here](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/service-discovery).
You should try one or all from this snippets in queue to make connection:

> @TargetApi(10) private BluetoothSocket connectDeviceUsingAPI10() throws IOException {
>
> ```
> BluetoothSocket socket = null;
> IOException ioex = null;
> int port = 1; // may be from 1 to 14 if I'm not confused
> UUID SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
>       
> // way #0. Connect using workaround for Android < 2.3
> try {
>      if (!isThreadActive)
>       return null;
>      Log.d("Try via API10: createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord");
>      socket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID); // or RFCOMM_UUID);
>      } catch (IOException e) { ioex = e; }
>       if (socket != null && ioex == null) {
>           try {
>               socket.connect();
>               setStreams(socket.getOutputStream(), socket.getInputStream());
>           } catch (IOException ex) {
>               ioex = ex;
>               try {
>                   socket.close();
>               } catch (IOException e) {
>               } finally {
>                   socket = null;
>               }
>           }
>       }
>       if (socket != null && ioex == null) {
>           return socket;
>
>       }
>
>       ioex = null;
>       socket = null;
>       // way #1. Using standard secure connection procedure via UUID
>       try {
>           if (!isThreadActive)
>               return null;
>           Log.d("Try via API10: createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord");
>           socket = mDevice
>                   .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);// or RFCOMM_UUID
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>           ioex = e;
>       }
>       if (socket != null && ioex == null) {
>           try {
>               socket.connect();
>               setStreams(socket.getOutputStream(), socket.getInputStream());
>           } catch (IOException ex) {
>               ioex = ex;
>               try {
>                   socket.close();
>               } catch (IOException e) {
>               } finally {
>                   socket = null;
>               }
>           }
>       }
>       if (socket != null && ioex == null) {
>           return socket;
>       }
>
>       // way #2. Using hidden api procedure with insecure socket
>       socket = null;
>       ioex = null;
>       // Try to fallback to API5 method
>       try {
>           if (!isThreadActive)
>               return null;
>           Log.d("Try via API10: createInsecureRfcommSocket");
>           Method m = mDevice.getClass().getMethod(
>                   "createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
>           socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mDevice, Integer.valueOf(port));
>       } catch (IOException e) { // ... }
>       if (socket != null && ioex == null) {
>           try {
>               socket.connect();
>               setStreams(socket.getOutputStream(), socket.getInputStream());
>           } catch (IOException ex) {
>               ioex = ex;
>               try {
>                   socket.close();
>               } catch (IOException e) {
>               } finally {
>                   socket = null;
>               }
>           }
>       }
>
>       if (socket != null && ioex == null) {
>           return socket;
>       }
>
>       ioex = null;
>       socket = null;
>       // way #3. Connect using workaround for Android < 2.3
>       try {
>           if (!isThreadActive)
>               return null;
>           Log.d("Try via API10: createRfcommSocket");
>           Method m = mDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
>                   new Class[] { int.class });
>           socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mDevice, Integer.valueOf(port));
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>               ioex = e;
>       }
>       if (socket != null && ioex == null) {
>           try {
>               socket.connect();
>               setStreams(socket.getOutputStream(), socket.getInputStream());
>           } catch (IOException ex) {
>               ioex = ex;
>               try {
>                   socket.close();
>               } catch (IOException e) {
>               } finally {
>                   socket = null;
>               }
>           }
>       }
>       if (socket != null && ioex == null) {
>           return socket;
>       }
>       return socket;
>   }
> ```